# AS400/IBM i Series: RSTLICPGM not found

Tags: ibm-midrange

We're running IBM i Series v6.1. I'm trying to set up SSH and need to run the RSTLICPGM program to install packages, but I get an error which says `qsh: 001-0019 Error found searching for command RSTLICPGM. No such path or directory.` I'm logged in to the highest permission user, so permissions should not be the issue. I will add that I do not see the program in the directory pointed to by the QSH environment path i.e. the bin folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RSTLICPGM is a CL command, not a QSHell one...

Try using the [system](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzahz/rzahzsystem.htm) QSH command to run the CL command...

```
system "RSTLICPGM LICPGM(xxxxxxx)"
```

Comment: Awesome that worked. However, I now get this error `CPF3D96: Objects for product 5733SC1 option 33 release *FIRST not restored.` Any ideas?

Comment: I would suggest not trying to invoke the command from QSH and just use the IBM i command line.  It sounds like the media you are using doesn't have the necessary licensed product on it.

Comment: I appreciate it, it seems that SSH was installed previously, so while I couldn't resolve `CPF3D96`, I didn't need to.